# How to swap image and video to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to swap image and the videos when user clicks a selected element

I have something like the following:

```
<div class='container'>
<h1 class='title'>Title</h1>
    <div class='row'>
         <div class='main'>
           <img class='col-md-7 col-sm-8 img-responsive' src='main.png'/>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
    <a href='#' class='component'><video class='video col-md-4 col-sm-4' controls><source   src='video1.mp4'/></video></a>
    <a href='#' class='component'><video class='video col-md-4 col-sm-4' controls><source src='video2.mp4'/></video></a>
    <a href='#' class='component'><img class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 img-responsive' src='img1.png'/></a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I want to swap the image or video to the `main` div whenever the user click the link. My js

```
$('.component').on('click', function(){
   var mainSrc = $(this).closest('.container').find('.main').html();
   var newSrc  = $(this).html();
   $(this).html(mainSrc)
   $(this).closest('.container').find('.main').html(newSrc);
})
```

My problem is that I am using `bootstrap` and if I copy the entire html under my `main` div, it carries the `col-md-4 col-sm-4` to the `main` div. It will shrink the `main` div width. How do I keep the same class under `main` div and `component` `a` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Take those classes out of the elements and create another wrapper div. You can assign it to .main as well, but I'm not too sure what you're doing with .main, so I'll just leave that alone.

```
<div class='container'>
  <h1 class='title'>Title</h1>
  <div class='row'>
       <div class='main'>
           <div class='col-md-7 col-sm-8 img-responsive'>
             <img class='img-responsive' src='main.png'/>
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <a href='#' class='component'>
      <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'>
        <video class='video' controls><source src='video1.mp4'/></video>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href='#' class='component'>
      <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'>
        <video class='video' controls><source src='video2.mp4'/></video>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href='#' class='component'>
      <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'>
        <img class='img-responsive' src='img1.png'/>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then you can do something like this to select and swap the media.

```
$('.component').on('click', function(){
   var mainSrc = $(this).closest('.container').find('.main:first-child').html();
   var newSrc  = $(this).children().first().html();
   $(this).html(mainSrc)
   $(this).closest('.container').find('.main:first-child').html(newSrc);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your HTML, [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/LpgBy/3/) of a solution.

```
$('.component').click(function () {
    var clickClass = $(this).children(0).attr("class");
    var mainClass = $(".main").children(0).attr("class");
    var clickHTML = $(this).html();
    var mainHTML = $(".main").html();
    $(this).html(mainHTML);
    $(".main").html(clickHTML);
    $(this).children(0).attr("class",clickClass);
    $(".main").children(0).attr("class",mainClass);
});
```

I have added Bootstrap but don't have the image files.