# How to swap images from side bar to the middle div on clicking on those sidebar images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to build a web page and I've 3 images of that product in my sidebar and one main image in the middle now I want to get the sidebar image in the middle when a user clicks on that sidebar image. I don't know how to go about this. I've already tried couple of ways which I've found online, one of them is this
1. [How to swap image and video to another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589391/how-to-swap-image-and-video-to-another-div)

But these are not working out for me. 
[image: This is the screenshot of my webpage]

Comment: Please provide the relevant  HTML, CSS and JavaScript of the page you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is save both images in a variable and then swap them. Look at the example below

```js
var imgleft,
    imgcenter,
    $center = $(".center img");
$(".sidebar img").click(function(){
  imgleft = $(this).attr("src");
  imgcenter = $center.attr("src");
  $center.attr("src", imgleft);
  $(this).attr("src", imgcenter);
});
```

```css
.sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.center{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin:25% auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x60">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50">
</div>
<div class="center">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x40">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's event handling (on each of your sidebar images) to solve this problem. First add the following java script code in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeToImage1(){
        if(centerImage.src != "[1st-image-url.*]"){
            centerImage.src = "[1st-image-url.*]";
        }
    }
    function changeToImage2(){
        if(centerImage.src != "[2nd-image-url.*]"){
            centerImage.src = "[2nd-image-url.*]";
        }
    }
    function changeToImage3(){
        if(centerImage.src != "[3rd-image-url.*]"){
            centerImage.src = "[3rd-image-url.*]";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then you can simply add the above functions in the onClick attributes of your three sidebar div's accordingly. This can be done like this:

```
<div id = "first" onclick = "changeToImage1()">
    ...
</div>
<div id = "second" onclick = "changeToImage2()">
    ...
</div>
<div id = "third" onclick = "changeToImage3()">
    ...
</div>
```